# Can't install "Composer Dependency Manager for PHP"

Tags: composer-php

```
root@rushan-PC:~# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The suhosin.executor.include.whitelist setting is incorrect.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini` or suhosin.ini (Example path [for Debian]: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini):
    suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar 

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
```

Terminal gives me this error. Before that, I installed php packages, there was some error 
"Unable to correct problems, you have delayed (held) broken packages." But I can install it with aptitude, instead of apt-get. Perhaps, this dynamic libraries errors because of Held packages? Or something...Please, I need some help there:(. Sorry, I'm just a beginner in Linux and programming. And sorry for my English, cuz I'm from Uzbekistan :(

Comment: Did you try to open /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and add the line `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar ` at the end, as suggested in the error message you get?

Comment: Added now, the warnings remained, but composer installed correctly! Thank you! So, now, these warnings will not prevent correct operation of php?

Comment: It depends of what you need to use in your PHP scripts. If you don't want to see these warnings anymore, install the corresponding packages on your system using aptitude: php5-mcrypt, php5-gd, php5-mysql, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to information in your error, you should edit your php.ini file (/etc/php5/cli/php.ini) and add the following line at the end

> suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your **php.ini** file (*/etc/php5/cli/php.ini*) and add the following line before the **END:** keywords.

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```